# How to change background element position?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

What I have right now only moves image for second then goes back to orginal position?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/formstyle.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function northwest(image) {

       var myElement;//create reference
       myElement = document.getElementById('image').style;
       myElement.top = "50px";
       myElement.left = "50px";
     }

    function northeast(image) {
       var myElement;//create reference
       myElement = document.getElementById('image').style;
       myElement.top = "14px";
       myElement.left = "1106px";
    }

    <title>Move It!</title>

</head>

<body>  
     <div id = "para">
        Blah Blah Blah Blah:)     </div>

     <div id ="image" ></div>

    <div id = "links">
    <form action = " ">
    <p >
        <a href="javascript: northwest('image')">move background image to the northwest</a>
        <a href="javascript: northeast('image')">move background image to the northeast</a>
        <a href="javascript: southwest('image')">move background image to the southwest</a>
        <a href="javascript: southwest('image')">move background image to the southwest</a>
    </p> 
    </form>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
#image {
        background-image:url('http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise4/images/kito.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 205px; 
        left: 456px; 
        color: inherit;
        width: 133px;
        height: 107px;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity:0.6;            
        } 

  #para {
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Arial;
        position: relative; 
        top: 73px; 
        left: 447px; 
        color: inherit;
        width: 132px;
        height: 341px;
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you declare your variables with the `var` keyword. Otherwise, they're thrust into the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this function attached to submit buttons. So you are submitting the form each time, essentially refreshing the page.

Consider making these anchors or buttons instead of submit. If you want to use submit, you need to stop the [default behavior](http://www.openjs.com/articles/prevent_default_action/).

Comment: Okay, so thanks to the article on default behavior, I was able to get the background element to move successuflly.  My next question would be how to move it to another place (or in my case corner of the page).  I have updated my code up top.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is that you retreive from the DOM before it is even loaded. Try putting the JavaScript on the bottom of the HTML file right before the closing body-tag. This is considered best-pratice by Google and Yahoo!.

Yet another problem I see is the way you retreive the DOM element.

I would do it like this:

```
var myElement; // creating a reference
myElement = document.getElementById("image"); // initialize the reference
```